# Ionic Login using PHP

Tags: ionic-framework

Hi guys i have my php file like this :

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_password,$mysql_database);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$data               = file_get_contents("php://input");
$dataJsonDecode     = json_decode($data);

$username =   mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $dataJsonDecode->username);
$password =   mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $dataJsonDecode->password);

echo $username.$password;
$query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE Username = '$username' and Password = '$password'";

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
$rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result);


/*  if ($rowcount != 0) {
    echo "Login Success";
    # code...
}else{
    echo "Login Failed";
}*/

mysqli_close($conn);
```

I'm using this php to retrieve my login function sent by ionic services.js

```
var baseUrl = 'http://mywebsite.com/'      
login: function (datalogin) {
      return $http.post(baseUrl + 'ionic_do_login.php', datalogin, {
          headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8;'
          }
      });
  }
```

this services is trigerred by my controller.js

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', function ($scope, $ionicPopup, Chats) {
$scope.showAlert = function (msg) {
    $ionicPopup.alert({
        title: msg.title,
        template: msg.message,
        okText: 'Ok',
        okType: 'button-positive'
    });
};

$scope.login = function (username, password) {
    if (!username) {
        $scope.showAlert({
            title: "Information",
            message: "Username mohon diisi"
        });
    } else if (!password) {
        $scope.showAlert({
            title: "Information",
            message: "Password mohon diisi"
        });
    } else {
        $scope.username = username;
        $scope.password = password;
        Chats.login({
            'username' : username,
            'password' : password
        }).then(function (res) {
            $scope.showAlert({
                title: "Information",
                message: res.data
            });
        });
```

But everytime i serve my apps, and try to echo, it doesn't return anything.

Any helps?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's something called CORS that's disabled in browsers. It might be blocking the request. Try and run the app on an emulator.

If your using mozilla [this](http://spenibus.net/files/gitbin/cors-everywhere-firefox-addon/) extension would help you enable CORS on your browser.

Comment: I've found the solution by changing content type on my services and php! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using new Cordova library , you have to enable http network access by install whitelist plugin . You can get it [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist) . By default , cordova block the cross origin access

Comment: I've found the solution by changing content type on my services and php! thanks!